# Need image path which is stored in res/drawable folder in Android so that i can send it to other server

Tags: android

I am new in Android. I am trying to develop application on Android which will capture an image. This image is sent to another server for further processing. To send the image across the internet to the other server, I have used `IQEngines` API which does OCR. It requires `File` object.

For simplicity, I have stored the image in res/drawable folder, and I want to get the path of that image so I can create `File` object using this path. I will pass this `File` object to `IQEngines` API.

Please help me to solve this. If anyone has some different idea to send an image online from Android application to `IQEngines` server, it will be really helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
String uriStr = "android.resource://" + PACKAGE_NAME + "/" + R.drawable.image; 
File imageFile = new File(URI uri);
```

Comment: /*This code i wrote is not working can u plz help....its giving file does not exist error.....*/      File test_file = null;
String str = "android.resource://com/example/android/"+R.drawable.stamp_fast_track;
test_file = new File(str); test_file.exists();

Comment: Can you try with android.resource://com.example.android/ + ... ?

Comment: hello i am searching for the same ?have u got solution for the same?pls help...if yes pls

Comment: This works fine for me.. But it returns 223234.png rather than filename.png.. How to solve that ?

Comment: its not working, my question is can we able to get path of drawable image